# C++, console Application, reading files from directory

Tags: c++, file, directory, loops

I have a directory and I want to read all the text files in it using C++ and having windows OS also using console application
I don't know the files' names or their number
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), especially the [`basic_directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-template-basic_directory_iterator).

Comment: When you click the second link in my answer and scroll down a little, there is a sample application that lists all the items in a directory. If you are not able to take it from there, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the C++ and portable way, follow the solution by @Space_C0wb0y and use boost.Filesystem, otherwise, if you want to get your hands dirty with the Windows APIs, you can use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)/[FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions.

You can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) an example related to them.

Comment: You're welcome. If you solved with this method you may mark my answer as accepted. :)
Still, keep in mind that if you need portability and C++ style the best method is the one suggested by Space_C0wb0y.

Comment: sorry again I found that it's windows application not console. is it true??